# Upgrade issue from 2.5.28 to joomla 3.4.1

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, upgrade, mootools

I have upgraded a site from 2.5.28 to 3.4.1.I followed the migration steps as specified in document. It says like it successfully upgraded to latest joomla version 3.4.1.

But if I go to home page it throws like this

> 500 - JHtmlBehavior::mootools not found.
>
> You may not be able to visit this page because of:
>
> an out-of-date bookmark/favourite a search engine that has an
>   out-of-date listing for this site a mistyped address you have no
>   access to this page The requested resource was not found. An error has
>   occurred while processing your request.
>
> Please try one of the following pages:
>
> Home Page
>
> If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

What should I do to resolve this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');` is the code you will need to look for. This was used up until Joomla 3.x, where is was changed.

I'd suggest you do a mass find with your text editor for the above code and once found, replace it with:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
```

It's most likely coming from your template, or an extension

Comment: Thanks Lodder . I tried that too.Its showing me a empty white page after changing that line of code in the whole site.

Comment: Ok...go to your Global Configuration and set error reporting to "development". Then report any errors you see

Comment: @Ram Try to avoid having conversations using comments. If you have another question, search the existing ones and if you think you have something new, just post a new question. Thanks!